# Swing Timer calling action performed twice

Tags: java, swing, timer, jlabel

I have a class that extends JLabel. I want to increase the text value in JLabel by 1 after every second. I have used swing timer for it. But it is incrementing 2 instead of 1. My guess is it is calling action performed two times instead of one time.

```
public class MineTimer extends JLabel{
    private Timer timer;
    int time = 0;

    public void start() {
        time = 0;
        timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {               
                setText("" + time++);
            }
        });


        timer.start();
    }
}
```

**Expected output:**
After 1 sec text of JLabel

```
1
```

After 2 sec text of JLabel

```
2
```

After 3 sec text of JLabel

```
3
```

**Actual output:**
After 1 sec text of JLabel

```
2
```

After 2 sec text of JLabel

```
4
```

After 3 sec text of JLabel

```
6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're calling timer.start() somewhere else? How does the code behave when you rewrite it like this?

```
public class MineTimer extends JLabel {
public void start() {
    new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        int time = 0;
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {               
            setText("" + time++);
        }
    }).start();
  }
}
```

Comment: I only modified the code in such way to make 100% sure that you don't call timer.start() somewhere else. If you did, then after my rewrite you should have gotten a compiler error. If 'start' was in fact called twice, each timer would increase the same variable, resulting in visible increments by 2 - in my solution the timer only has it's own variable, inaccessible from anywhere else, preventing such behavior. It was just a guess, I'd have to have seen your whole code as it was before to see what was actually wrong.

Comment: I was not calling start anywhere else. Otherwise, according to you, I would have gotten an error that I didn't get. But anyways thanks.